# Laravel Local Package Dependency Issues

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

In my main composer.json file in the root of my Laravel app I have the following:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
    "company/package": "dev"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Company\\Package\\": "packages/company/package/src"
    }
},
```

Then in my package's composer.json file I have this line:

```
"require": {
    "zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev"
```

When I run **composer update** from the root directory, I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - company/package dev-feature/auth requires zizaco/entrust 5.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by zizaco/entrust[5.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your r
equirements or minimum-stability.
    - company/package dev-feature/auth requires zizaco/entrust 5.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by zizaco/entrust[5.2.x-dev] but these conflict with your r
equirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for company/package dev-feature/auth -> satisfiable by company/package[dev-feature/auth].
```

I am not sure exactly what is happening? What exactly is the constraint or requirement that is the causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the issue. In my root composer.json file I changed the following and now it works:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",
    "company/package": "dev-auth"
},
```